# A good web 'desktop' JavaScript, CSS, or both, library that likes ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I've come across, in passing, several suites of functions, widgets, frameworks, etc. that seek to produce a desktop like experience on the web.  Most are JavaScript and CSS tools that handle web content on an emulation of the desktop-paradigmed UI, e.g. TreeView + Content == Explorer.

Is there such a library nicely compatible with ASP.NET Forms without weeks of grief?  I'll also settle for something similar, but instead of native ASP.NET, a library for any of the open source CMS products for ASP.NET.   (Umbraco is at the top of my list, followed by mojoPortal.  I aspire to the level of coding their creators easily demonstrate in the product.

[PS, I don't want a 'desktop' ux per se, just light and simple dynamic layout for drag 'n drop, dock windows, a dock bar?.. and other fancy magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [ExtJs](http://www.extjs.com/) for an application as it is quite feature rich. Although you could wrap its components as ASP.NET controls as some have done, you'd still have to handle all events client-side in Javascript. I think the best is to get used to declaring and building your whole UI in Javascript and use ASP.NET only to communicate the data using HttpHandlers or some of the new MVC Ajax helpers.

Comment: I used and enjoyed extJs at my previous job.  Our whole UI was extJs, with ASP.NET only doing security and request management basically.  However, I think I need a middle ground until I'm better on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for [Yahoo UI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/dd/)